# Mongodb Text Search and ID field

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I want to search multiple fields in a collection for a phrase/string. I also need to filter the results to a single ID field.

For example, search the users collection for "john"

```
db.users.runCommand( "text", { search: "john" } )
```

When the document looks like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("525d5f3fa385ab082e8b4693"),
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" : "Doe",
    "email" : "john@doe.com",
    "account_id" : 1,
    "updated_at" : ISODate("2013-10-15T15:29:03.951Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2013-10-15T15:29:03.951Z")
}
```

What's the best way to also filter the results to a specific ID, in the case above "account_id", so I'd only be searching/returning results where "john" appears and the account_id equals "1" for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is done using the filter option:

```
db.users.runCommand( "text", {
                                   search: "john",
                                   filter: { account_id : 1 }
                                 }
                       )
```

Or from the docs - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/